# Should I start over my project in a new Django Virtual Environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I began my project **without** creating a virtual environment. Now I am wondering how big of a mistake was that. `pip install Pillow` not executing no matter what I do to include an image in my classs Model. **Can or should I migrate my files to a new virtual environment. Or should I start coding from scratch.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to start coding from the scratch. You can create a new virtual env using `python -m venv <name-of-the-env>` and install your dependencies.

Comment: Understood......Is it possible to guide me why I am getting this error...will be doing my own research in the meantime........`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" list': The system cannot find the file specified.`